# jQuery append excess menu items to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have a horiztonal menu in my admin area. When there are more than 8 items, I want to add a "More" item, which, when clicked, slides out a div with the excess menu items shown in it.

At the minute, I am just trying to append the excess menu items to the div. I have added the div to my adin area, it's got the ID more_menu. Here is the jQuery I have so far, but currently it doesn't work:

```
$('ul#adminmenu:has(li.menu-top:gt(8))').each(function() {
          $(this).append('<li id="more" class="menu-top menu-top-first menu-top-last"><a class="open_more_menu" href="#"><div class="wp-menu-name">More</div></a></li>');
          var lis = $(this).find('li.menu-top:gt(8)').not('#more');
          $(this).find('#more_menu ul').append(lis);
    });
```

This successfully adds the more item to the menu, but ignores how many menu items there are already. Also, it doesn't append the extra menu items to the #more_menu div

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question ? What is purpose of `:has()` at selector ?  Creating , appending duplicate `#more` `id`s to document within `.each()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

html

```
<ol id="menu">
  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
  <li>At, consequatur.</li>
  <li>Ut, ipsam.</li>
  <li>Ullam, nulla.</li>
  <li>Similique, dolore!</li>
  <li>Dolores, quibusdam.</li>
  <li>Ea, impedit!</li>
  <li>Quibusdam, delectus.</li>
  <li>Consequatur, tempore?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
  <li>At, consequatur.</li>
  <li>Ut, ipsam.</li>
  <li>Ullam, nulla.</li>
  <li>Similique, dolore!</li>
  <li>Dolores, quibusdam.</li>
  <li>Ea, impedit!</li>
  <li>Quibusdam, delectus.</li>
  <li>A Consequatur, tempore?</li>
</ol>
<ul id="more_menu">

</ul>
```

css

```
#more_menu {
  display: none;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var count = $('#menu').children().length;
  var limit = 8;
  if (count > 8) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= count - limit; i++) {
        $('#more_menu').append($('#menu').children().eq(limit));
    }
    $('#menu').append('<li><a href="" class="more">Show more</a></li>');
  }

  $('#menu').on('click', '.more', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#more_menu').toggle();
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oa4zLrvp/2/

You can switch out the toggle for the #more_menu for a toggleClass that defines the css animation you're using to slide out the menu

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer solved your issue, would you please mark it as accepted? Thanks!